# Limit a number of words in a div with jQuery

Tags: jquery, trim

I would like to limit a number of words in a div with jQuery to make my Website title look better.

I already tried the solution below but unfortunately it cut the words in half what it’s rubbish.

```
<div class="entry-title">Auxerunt haec vulgi sordidioris audaciam, quod cum ingravesceret penuria commeatuum</div>
```

---

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$(".entry-title").text(function(index, currentText) {
return currentText.substr(0, 20);
});
});
```

This one count the character I would like one that counts the words.

Thanks for the Help.

Comment: Are you sure you want to do this with jQuery? CSS does a much better job at this using the `text-overflow` property.

Comment: Fauxserious can you show me the css way, just I want the content on 2 line not only one. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

[`split()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) the text into an array of *n* words, then [`join()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) them.

```js
$(".entry-title").text(function(index, currentText) {
  return currentText
           .split(' ', 4) //create array of the first four words
           .join(' ');    //join the array with spaces
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="entry-title">Auxerunt haec vulgi sordidioris audaciam, quod cum ingravesceret penuria commeatuum</div>
```